# calculating delta time between records in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have an interesting problem, I am trying to calculate the delta time between records done at different locations.

```
id x y time
1  x1 y1 10
1  x1 y1 12
1  x2 y2 14
2  x4 y4 8
2  x5 y5 12
```

I am trying to get some thing like

```
id x y time delta
1 x1 y1 10   4
1 x2 y2 14   0
2 x4 y4 8    4
2 x5 y5 12   0
```

I have done this type of processing with HiveQL by using custom UDTF but was thinking how can I achieve this with DataFrame in general (may it be in R, Pandas, PySpark). Ideally, I am trying to find a solution for Python pandas and pyspark.

Any hint is appreciated, thank you for your time !

Comment: Why row `1  x1 y1 12` is missing in output?

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby(['id'])['time'].diff()` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael row 1 is missing because this record was done is same location as row 0, I trying to find the delta time at different locations. I can do group by only after I remove the multiple records done at each location. I always want to keep the 1st record made at a location.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is a bit problematic answer, because in real there can be more rows, but do you need `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','x','y'])` and then `df['delta'] = df.groupby(['id'])['time'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael thank you for the hints, it was very useful, here is the code `import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sampleInput.txt", header=None,usecols=[0,1,2,3], names=['id','x','y','time'],sep="\t")
delta = df.groupby(['id','x','y']).first().reset_index()
delta['delta'] = delta.groupby('id')['time'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `groupby` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.Series.shift.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','x','y']).copy()

df1['delta'] = df1.groupby(['id'])['time'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

Final code:

```
import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv("sampleInput.txt", 
                                      header=None,
                                      usecols=[0,1,2,3], 
                                      names=['id','x','y','time'],
                                      sep="\t") 

delta = df.groupby(['id','x','y']).first().reset_index() 
delta['delta'] = delta.groupby('id')['time'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [111]: %timeit df.groupby(['id','x','y']).first().reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.42 ms per loop

In [112]: %timeit df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','x','y']).copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 658 µs per loop
```

Comment: I think faster is use `drop_duplicates`, I add `copy` if need create new `DataFrame`

Comment: thank you, yes it looks faster, before that I encountered, this code is sensitive to unordered time field, any ideas on ordering within grouped objects (w.r.t time)? and then call diff() on sorted grouped items. In anycase, I have to use groupby id after I remove duplicates.

Comment: Yes, you can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) -  `df = df.sort_values(by='id')`

Comment: on data frames, yes sort_values is the way, but interestingly, it doesn't work on the groupedDataFrame object

Comment: You need convert `groupedDataFrame object` to `DataFrame`, use `reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael thank you for the hints, it was very useful, here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sampleInput.txt", header=None,usecols=[0,1,2,3], names=['id','x','y','time'],sep="\t")
delta = df.groupby(['id','x','y']).first().reset_index()
delta['delta'] = delta.groupby('id')['time'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

That takes

```
1   x1  y1  10
1   x1  y1  12
1   x2  y2  14
2   x4  y4  8
2   x5  y5  12
```

and gives,

```
   id   x   y  time  delta
0   1  x1  y1    10      4
1   1  x2  y2    14      0
2   2  x4  y4     8      4
3   2  x5  y5    12      0
```